# C++ begin/end(arr) on a pointer - no matching function for call to ‘begin(int**&)’

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I'd like to get length of an array. I have this code:

```
#include <iterator>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

void printArrLen(int arr[]);

int testArr [3] = {1, 4, 5};

int main() {
  printArrLen(testArr);
  cout << "main/testArr; Memory address: " << testArr << ", value: " << *testArr << endl;
  cout << end(testArr) << endl;
}

void printArrLen(int arr[]) {
  cout << "printArrLen/arr; Memory address: " << arr << ", value: " << *arr << endl;
  cout << "printArrLen/testArr; Memory address: " << testArr << ", value: " << *testArr << endl;
  // This works:
  cout << end(testArr) << endl;
  // This doesn't work - no matching function for call to 'end(int*&)':
  // cout << end(arr) << endl;
  // Doesn't work:
  // cout << "arrLen: " << end(arr) - begin(arr) << endl;    
}
```

Output:

```
printArrLen/arr; Memory address: 0x601318, value: 1
printArrLen/testArr; Memory address: 0x601318, value: 1
0x601324
main/testArr; Memory address: 0x601318, value: 1
0x601324
```

Uncommenting `cout << end(arr) << endl;` in printArrLen gives `no matching function for call to 'end(int*&)'`

I'm aware that `begin/end(arr)` wont work if `arr` is a pointer.
Why do they work on testArr in printArrLen and main, if the testArr seems to be a pointer too? How it can be proven in printArrLen that `testArr` is not a pointer and `arr` is while they both seem to contain a memory address?

Comment: `testArr` is an array. When pass an array to function (except for by reference) it will decay to pointer. So `arr` is a pointer.

Comment: Arrays have a length. A pointer is technically just a pointer to a single value, it has no "length".

Comment: You use `c++`. Why not using `std::array`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'd like to get length of an array.
>
> [...]
>
> ```
> void printArrLen(int arr[]);
> ```

Not like this. `arr` in this function is actually a **pointer to the first element** of the array. Or more precisely, it *may* point to the first element of an array. It's just an `int*` and could point anywhere. In any case, there *is* no size information anymore inside of the function. You simply cannot get it.

The `[]` syntax is just there to confuse you. But don't take my word on it -- ask your compiler by trying this piece of code:

```
void printArrLen(int arr[]) {}
void printArrLen(int* arr) {}
```

You will see that it will complain about a redefinition.

> ```
> int testArr [3] = {1, 4, 5};
> ```

`testArr`, in contrast to the `arr` parameter above, *is* an array, and carries the size information in its type.

> ```
> int main() {
>   printArrLen(testArr);
> ```

Here you pass to the function a pointer to the first element of `testArr`, i.e. an `int*` pointing to the "1" element.

> ```
>  // This works:
>   cout << end(testArr) << endl;
> ```

Because `testArr` is an array.

> ```
>   // This doesn't work - no matching function for call to 'end(int*&)':
>   // cout << end(arr) << endl;
> ```

Because `arr` is a pointer.

---

Use `std::vector` if the array's size is only known at runtime, or `std::array` if it's already known at compile time. Both containers always know their own size.

---

> How it can be proven in printArrLen that `testArr` is not a pointer
>   and `arr` is while they both seem to contain a memory address?

This question makes less sense than it seems.

Consider this:

```
int main()
{
    int i = 0;
    double d = 0.0;
}
```

Now, how can you "prove" that `i` is not a `double` but `d` is?

The answer is that you do not have to "prove" it, because, obviously, you already know.

Technically, there is another answer to your question, of course, and that is using [`typeid`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/typeid)...

```
#include <typeinfo>
#include <typeindex>
#include <iostream>

void printArrLen(int arr[]);

int testArr [3] = {1, 4, 5};
int anotherTestArr [3] = {1, 4, 5};
int yetAnotherTestArr [4] = {1, 4, 5, 6};

int main() {
  printArrLen(testArr);
}

void printArrLen(int arr[]) {
  std::cout << (std::type_index(typeid(arr)) == std::type_index(typeid(testArr))) << "\n";
  std::cout << (std::type_index(typeid(anotherTestArr)) == std::type_index(typeid(testArr))) << "\n";
  std::cout << (std::type_index(typeid(yetAnotherTestArr)) == std::type_index(typeid(testArr))) << "\n";
}
```

This does not have any direct use for you, but it is of great educational value. It will print:

```
0
1
0
```

This example demonstrates that arrays of different sizes are different types, and pointers are different types from all array types.

Comment: Thanks. This answer is the most comprehensive of all. My second question makes sense for me for educational purposes :).

Answer (score 2):

> I'm aware that begin/end(arr) wont work if arr is a pointer. Why do they work on testArr in printArrLen and main, if the testArr seems to be a pointer too?

Pointers are not arrays.

In your code,

- `testArr` is array which has been initialised with 3 elements.
- `arr` is array parameter. Array parameter is special in the sense that the array `decays` to pointer, so what is actually passed to the function `printArrLen` is a pointer (to `arr` first element).

Btw, you don't have to provide array size when you initialise it. This would do as well (and better):

```
int testArr[] = {1, 4, 5};
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. The source of my confusion is that testArr/arr and *testArr/*arr behave the same when printing them on the screen so I can't tell that they are different.

Comment: @M.M yes, it should be what you said. Also, it can be `formal argument` and `actual argument`

Comment: @Alan not sure what you are saying, `testArr/arr` is invalid code - you should get a compile error

Comment: @artm: sorry, this was a shortcut, just squeezed variable names together. testArr/arr = `testArr` and `arr`

Answer (score 1):

`testArr` is not a pointer, it is an array with `3` elements.

`arr` is a pointer - there is not enough knowledge to make `begin` and `end` work, because the compiler does not know that it's pointing to an array *(and what the size of the hypothetical array is)*.

My suggestion is: use either `std::array` or `std::vector`, depending on what you need to do. If you want to use old-school arrays, change `printArrLen` to take an array reference:

```
template <size_t N>
void printArrLen(int (&arr)[N]) {
    /* ... */
}
```

[**wandbox example**](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/dlbCCyZquxMdstUE)

Comment: So I assume that 'couting' testArr and arr and getting a memory address, and *testArr and *arr and getting first elements' values in both cases doesn't mean, that they are both pointers. I'd have extra question then: how can I tell, if possible, that testArr and arr are different?

Comment: @Alan: When you send an array to `cout`, then the same mechanism as in your `printArrLen` kicks in: the array is treated as a pointer to the array's first element. So you have a pointer. And when a pointer is sent to `cout`, then the address is printed (not counting the special treatment for `char*`, of course).

Comment: @ChristianHackl: I get it now. cout will always print a pointer to array, whether I pass an array or array pointer to it. That's why they seem the be both pointers while actually they are not. Thanks!

Comment: @Alan: "pointer to array" sounds slightly wrong. Think of it exactly as I said: a pointer to the first element. A "pointer to array" might be confused with a pointer to that pointer, i.e. an `int**`.